Issue with `gghdr` package not producing HDR boxplots
I am currently experiencing an issue with the gghdr package in R. I'm trying to generate HDR boxplots, but I keep getting an error message. The code I'm using is as follows:
library(ggplot2)
library(gghdr)
ggplot(faithful, aes(y = eruptions)) +
  geom_hdr_boxplot()

However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:
Error in if (guide$reverse) { : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: y.
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a
  factor?

If anyone could provide some insight into what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!

To get help, it would be useful to have some data to work with to attempt to reproduce & fix the error you are getting. You can use dput() for that.

The dataset faithful is included with the mentioned packages.

The issue is that {gghdr} has been unmaintained for a few years and has been archived by CRAN. Fixes have been proposed and people have offered to take over maintainership, but the author appears unresponsive.

You can install the proposed fix from github with pak::pak("Sayani07/gghdr#25"). Disclaimer: I'm the one that proposed this fix. You'll be greeted by a wall of warnings, but it should work.
# pak::pak("Sayani07/gghdr#25")

library(ggplot2)
library(gghdr)

ggplot(faithful, aes(y = eruptions)) +
  geom_hdr_boxplot()
#> Warning: The dot-dot notation (`..prob..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `after_stat(prob)` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: y.
#> ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in
#>   the data.
#> ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical
#>   variable into a factor?
#> Warning: The `scale_name` argument of `discrete_scale()` is deprecated as of ggplot2
#> 3.5.0.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: The S3 guide system was deprecated in ggplot2 3.5.0.
#> ℹ It has been replaced by a ggproto system that can be extended.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `linewidth`.
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic with geom_rect was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` aesthetic instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `linewidth`.
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic with geom_segment was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` aesthetic instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you, @teunbrand. Do you know any other package that integrates with ggplot2 and allows to produce HDR boxplots?

Unfortunately, I don't know of such packages.

Thanks, let's hope the package maintainer passes the duties to other interested R users.
